# How to deal with answers that should be comments when user doesn't have the appropriate rep

Tags: discussion, moderation

See this answer.

[Re-racking in a Buffalo Trace whiskey barrel](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/re-racking-in-a-buffalo-trace-whiskey-barrel/3506#3506)

How should we deal with it?

Comment: Test answer to move to comment

Answer (score 4):

I just moved it to a comment automatically before thinking "oh, maybe I should leave it so other people can see this..."

But, I think we just move them to comments. And hopefully people flag them so we see them.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: never mind, I just saw that on the mod menu. Thanks for the knowledge